# Razor Syntax in MVC with VB - Conditional Markup

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, syntax

In my view, I'm writing like this:

```
@Code
    For Each item in Model
        @<div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="~/thumbs/@(item.username).png" alt="">
        </div>
    Next
End Code
```

And that works fine! But, I want to add some extra line of code that should execute on every 6th iteration of the loop (starting from 0). So I modified the code as below:

```
@Code
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For Each item in Model

        @IIf(count Mod 6 = 0, "<div class='row'>", "") ' This line Executes on every 6th iteration

        @<div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="~/thumbs/@(item.username).png" alt="">
        </div>

        @IIf(count Mod 6 = 0, "</div>", "") ' This line Executes on every 6th iteration

        count += 1
    Next
End Code
```

But rather than adding the markups `<div class='row'>` and `</div>`; it writes the raw string (as if I've written `&lt;div class='row'&gt;` and `&lt;/div&gt;`) on the page! What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fellas; I got the answer. What I did is:

```
@Code
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For Each item in Model

        @IIf(count Mod 6 = 0, @Html.Raw("<div class='row'>"), "") ' This line Executes on every 6th iteration

        @<div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="~/thumbs/@(item.username).png" alt="">
        </div>

        @IIf(count Mod 6 = 0, @Html.Raw("</div>"), "") ' This line Executes on every 6th iteration

        count += 1
    Next
End Code
```